# Android Firestore: Failed to gain exclusive lock to the Firestore client's offline persistence

Tags: android, android-studio, service, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an Android application in which I update user's location every 10 seconds. For this, I run a timerTask in a Service and write LatLng values to Firestore database.

The following is my timerTask class.

```java
class UploadDataTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(mLatLong));

                mFireStore.collection(Constants.LOCATION_REFERENCE).document(mUser.getUid()).set(mLatLong).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Upload successful.");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error when I try to write this data to Firestore.

```java
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sarthak.trackit.trackit:my_service, PID: 24286
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeux.run(Unknown Source:23)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to gain exclusive lock to the Firestore client's offline persistence. This generally means you are using Firestore from multiple processes in your app. Keep in mind that multi-process Android apps execute the code in your Application class in all processes, so you may need to avoid initializing Firestore in your Application class. If you are intentionally using Firestore from multiple processes, you can only enable offline persistence (i.e. call setPersistenceEnabled(true)) in one of them.
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeqn.start(Unknown Source:34)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zza(Unknown Source:54)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenh.run(Unknown Source:8)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:634)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:320)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:294)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:833)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:818)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:721)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:740)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:300)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:254)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:194)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeqn.start(Unknown Source:19)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenf.zza(Unknown Source:54) 
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzenh.run(Unknown Source:8) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuu$zza.run(Unknown Source:7) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have searched a lot but have not been quite able to find the issue. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the data in the application manager on the device and then run the app again?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I tried clearing app data and even reinstalling the application. However, it did not seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

`Firestore` can't be acceded from a different thread than it own at the first write operation because is the time when the reference to the local db is created, keep in mind that `Firestore` runs all their operations asynchronously(they don't block the calling thread) but their callbacks are called on the main looper, meaning, looking at your code, the issue for you is solved removing the post to the handler and *recommendable* passing an executor for the callback, something as:

```
mFireStore.collection(Constants.LOCATION_REFERENCE).document(mUser.getUid()).set(mLatLong).addOnCompleteListener(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Upload successful.");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for response. :) Let me try your solution and revert back.